# Why does my voice have low volume during calls?

Tags: iphone, audio, call

When calling, or recording voice messages, with the phone app, my voice has a very low volume, such that it's almost inaudible.

I disabled noise cancellation in the accessibility settings, which improved it a little but it's still low.

It seems to vary between apps. The Voice Memos app is loud and clear, and Telegram and WhatsApp are somewhere in the middle.

I don't see audio settings specific to the apps.

Any ideas?